# "Protected" Records and profiles permissions

Tags: custom-object, permissions, validation-rule, before-trigger

In our org, we have a custom object, which all records meeting specific criteria need to be protected (criteria is `StartDate older than 3 months`)

By '*protected records*' we mean:

1. for some specific roles,reject any changes done on those records, no
   matter from where they are done (page layout of record, updates from
   lightning component or VF manipulating any field or child record)
2. for some other roles, we would like to authorize changes, but show a
   confirmation pop-up if the change is done from the standard record
   page

How would I achieve that ?

**Update** (sorry for the unclear request !) :

I have declared a global setting, and can use validation rules to accept/revoke changes to records. To my knowledge, I can access user's profile in Apex Trigger.
What I can't figure out is how to ask for confirmation & get the callback to update ? and whether this custom setting can be edited by specific profiles ?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please see [ask] and make an [edit] to show us your work so far and the specific problem you are encountering.

Comment: @DavidReed thank you for the clarification, please let me know is you need any more detail !

Answer (score 0):

> we would like to authorize changes, but show a confirmation pop-up if the change is done from the standard record page
>   [...]
>
> > What I can't figure out is how to ask for confirmation & get the callback to update ?

You can't inject code into the standard record page to run on save. You would need to override the entire record edit action with a Visualforce page or Lightning component, which is a very heavyweight solution.

Another option would be to reject the save with an error message unless the user has checked a "Yes, I really want to do this" box on the record, and then reset the checkbox in a trigger. The user experience may not be exactly what you want, but it's certainly lighter-weight.

> and whether this custom setting can be edited by specific profiles ?

Editing Custom Settings requires [Customize Application](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cs_detail.htm&type=5) permission. If you expose the Custom Setting via a custom user interface, such as a Visualforce page, you will need to permission it explicitly to specific profiles (after a recent Critical Update is enabled).